# Convert Uint8List to String with Dart

Tags: arrays, string, dart

cipher.process returns an Uint8List which is a list of unsigned integers (0-255). I need to convert this Uint8List to a string that I can easily convert back to the same Uint8List.

```dart
    var cipherText = cipher.process( inputAsUint8List );        
    return ASCII.decode(cipherText);
```

ASCII.decode throws an error since some of the integers are > 127.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I guess this should do it:

```dart
String s = new String.fromCharCodes(inputAsUint8List);
var outputAsUint8List = new Uint8List.fromList(s.codeUnits);
```

Comment: This won't work for UTF8 characters which use more than 2 bytes, better to use dart:convert UTF8.encode()/decode().

Comment: The output of `cipher.process` is plain bytes, so you can pick any valid interpretation for them. Using `UTF8.decode` may break because the bytes are not valid UTF-8, but `String.fromCharCodes` will treat the bytes as Latin-1, which is always valid. Another possibility is to convert the bytes to a Uint16List, storing two bytes in each character (but that gets complicated if there is an odd number of bytes).

Comment: If the output is just plain bytes, then it probably makes sense to display them as base64 or hex.

Comment: @Im What is `cipher.process`? Is it from a package?

Comment: This will not work for UTF16 characters like ć, č, ü etc as they have two bytes and Uint8List.fromList truncates ints to 8-bit ints, takes lower 8-bits from that integer, so you will get garbage when you convert back.

Answer (score 25):

To answer the specific question. I haven't used cipher.process, and can't find the docs. But if it just returns raw bytes, then perhaps these would be best encoded as hexidecimal or base64.

Have a look at [CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/crypto/0.9.0/index.html#crypto/crypto.CryptoUtils@id_bytesToBase64), and [CryptoUtils.bytesToHex](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/crypto/0.9.0/index.html#crypto/crypto.CryptoUtils@id_bytesToHex).

To answer the general question in the title, if the Uint8List contains UTF8 text, then use utf8.decode() from the dart:convert library. See the [api docs](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:convert#id_UTF8).

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  var encoded = utf8.encode("Îñţérñåţîöñåļîžåţîờñ");
  var decoded = utf8.decode([0x62, 0x6c, 0xc3, 0xa5, 0x62, 0xc3, 0xa6,
                           0x72, 0x67, 0x72, 0xc3, 0xb8, 0x64]);
}
```

[String.fromCharCodes()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.String#id_String-fromCharCodes) takes a list of UTF-16 code units as input.

Also see [LATIN1](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:convert#id_LATIN1) which will behave the same as String.fromCharCodes when the input is < 0xFF.

Comment: `LATIN1.decode` and `String.fromCharCodes()` will do the same thing on an Uint8List since Latin-1 is a subset of Unicode.

Comment: `UTF8` has become `utf8` now?

Answer (score 15):

```
Uint8List x;
Utf8Decoder().convert(x);
```

Comment: Not every byte sequence is a valid UTF8 string.

Comment: If you set `Utf8Decoder(allowMalformed = true)` then convert replaces invalid (or unterminated) character sequences with the Unicode Replacement character `U+FFFD` (�).

Answer (score 7):

Dart uses UTF-16 to store `String`s. For now in Dart there is no simple way of converting it easly to bytes and backwards. Therefore, you can use raw calculations to convert `String` to `Uint8List` and backwards.

Dart code:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  // Source
  String source = 'Hello! Cześć! 你好! ご挨拶！Привет! ℌ! !';
  print(source.length.toString() + ': "' + source + '" (' + source.runes.length.toString() + ')');

  // String (Dart uses UTF-16) to bytes
  var list = new List<int>();
  source.runes.forEach((rune) {
    if (rune >= 0x10000) {
      rune -= 0x10000;
      int firstWord = (rune >> 10) + 0xD800;
      list.add(firstWord >> 8);
      list.add(firstWord & 0xFF);
      int secondWord = (rune & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00;
      list.add(secondWord >> 8);
      list.add(secondWord & 0xFF);
    }
    else {
        list.add(rune >> 8);
        list.add(rune & 0xFF);
    }
  });
  Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(list);

  // Here you have `Uint8List` available

  // Bytes to UTF-16 string
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length;) {
    int firstWord = (bytes[i] << 8) + bytes[i + 1];
    if (0xD800 <= firstWord && firstWord <= 0xDBFF) {
      int secondWord = (bytes[i + 2] << 8) + bytes[i + 3];
      buffer.writeCharCode(((firstWord - 0xD800) << 10) + (secondWord - 0xDC00) + 0x10000);
      i += 4;
    }
    else {
        buffer.writeCharCode(firstWord);
      i += 2;
    }
  }

  // Outcome
  String outcome = buffer.toString();  
  print(outcome.length.toString() + ': "' + outcome + '" (' + outcome.runes.length.toString() + ')');
}
```

Result:

```
52: "Hello! Cześć! 你好! ご挨拶！Привет! ℌ! !" (43)
52: "Hello! Cześć! 你好! ご挨拶！Привет! ℌ! !" (43)
```

[Run it online](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/cc2950856582932af91d22fa1dc981fc)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
String uint8ListToHexString(Uint8List uint8list) {
    var hex = "";
    for (var i in uint8list) {
    var x = i.toRadixString(16);
    if(x.length == 1){
      x = "0$x";
    }
    hex += x;
 }
 return hex;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This working for me.

```
final Uint8List fileData = const Utf8Encoder().convert('My String Value');
```