# convert a String of "uint8list" to a Unit8List

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a memory image stored in Sqllite converted to String with the toString() method, I want to convert it to Unit8List to display it inside a MemoryImage widget

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`codeUnits` gets you a `List<int>`
`Uint8List.fromList(...)` converts `List<int>` to `Uint8List`
`String.fromCharCodes(...)` converts `List<int>` or `Uint8List` to `String`

```
List<int> list = 'xxx'.codeUnits;
Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(list);
String string = String.fromCharCodes(bytes);
```

Comment: Isn't there problem with UTF-16 characters?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's possible. Should be easy to try.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem (online code [confirmation](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f2b915b32ad42e96f04eb11b5d916a78)). I will try my best to come up with updated answer.

Comment: Hi @PsychoX, any link to  UTF-16 working version ? Thanks.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I test with `x√xx` and  `x√x周x`，output is `xxx` and `xxhx`, here's the [gist link](https://gist.github.com/57bead40f336151113373fce37247b17)

Comment: Find a more generic answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54844226/1530581

Comment: There is universal solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565242/convert-uint8list-to-string-with-dart/56363052#56363052

Comment: Warning: Uint8List.fromList(list) will truncate your integers to 8-bit integers.

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS WRONG. Use utf8 encoding or face the consequences.

Answer (score 14):

Use `utf8.encode(myString)` to convert String to bytes or `List<int>`,

And then convert it back using `utf8.decode(bytes)`

```
String source = 'Błonie';

List<int> list = utf8.encode(source);
Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(list);
String outcome = utf8.decode(bytes);
```

Answer (score 3):

the best and simple way of doing it is,

```
import 'dart:convert';

Image.memory(base64Decode(string_value_here));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uint8List convertStringToUint8List(String str) {
  final List<int> codeUnits = str.codeUnits;
  final Uint8List unit8List = Uint8List.fromList(codeUnits);

  return unit8List;
}
```

By Phuc Tran

Comment: if you are referencing material written by others, you need to follow all the rules in [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)