# Problems loading images from bytes in Flutter/Dart

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flutter, dart, graphql

I am building an application with Flutter. I am using using a mix of newer technologies that I am struggling to piece together.

My actual issue is that I cannot get images to load in the app when using the following methods:

1. Insert test data into MongoDB using Mongoengine, images are inserted into GridFS using [this method](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/gridfs.html).
2. Query GraphQL server for data and retrieve data and receive images from GridFS in form of `bytes` but in a `string` - e.g "b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4V0X .... '"
3. Use that bytes string to load images in app with something like [Image.memory()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html)

But the images fail to load with an error: `type String is not a subtype of type Uint8List`. So I tried to convert the string of bytes from a String to raw bytes by doing:

```
List<int> bytesList = imageData['image']['data'].codeUnits;
Uint8List thumbImageBytes = Uint8List.fromList(bytesList);
```

I get the following exception:

```
I/flutter ( 4303): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞══════
I/flutter ( 4303): The following _Exception was thrown while resolving an image:
I/flutter ( 4303): Exception: Could not instantiate image codec.
```

I have no idea what I can do to fix this, I cannot seem to find anything by googling etc. It would seem there is no information available for this exact scenario except for [this S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613234/convert-a-string-of-uint8list-to-a-unit8list) which is what I have tried to do. I have also tried all the methods sugested in comments, followed the suggested links and tried all available combinations of answers, comments, everything.

My set up is as follows;

Main app: Flutter/Dart
API Server: Python/Flask/Mongoengine based GraphQL/Graphene API
Backend Database: MongoDB

The Python side;

A Mongoengine Document model:

```
class Product(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'product'}
    name = StringField(unique=True)
    price = FloatField()
    sale_price = FloatField()
    description = StringField()
    image = FileField()
    thumb = FileField()
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    edited_at = DateTimeField()
    # user = ReferenceField(User)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Product Model::name: {self.name}>'
```

A Graphene schema for the model:

```
class ProductAttribute:
    name = graphene.String()
    price = graphene.Float()
    sale_price = graphene.Float()
    description = graphene.String()
    image = Upload()
    thumb = graphene.String()
    created_at = graphene.DateTime()
    edited_at = graphene.DateTime()

class Product(MongoengineObjectType):
    """Product node."""

    class Meta:
        model = ProductModel
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)

class CreateProductInput(graphene.InputObjectType, ProductAttribute):
    """Arguments to create a product."""
    pass

class CreateProduct(graphene.Mutation):
    """Create a product."""
    product = graphene.Field(lambda: Product, description="Product created by this mutation.")

    class Arguments:
        input = CreateProductInput()
        image = Upload(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, image, input):
        data = utils.input_to_dictionary(input)
        data['created_at'] = datetime.utcnow()
        data['edited_at'] = datetime.utcnow()
        print(data)

        product = ProductModel(**data)
        product.save()

        return CreateProduct(product=product)
```

My base Graphene schema:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    """Query objects for GraphQL API."""

    node = graphene.relay.Node.Field()
    single_product = graphene.relay.Node.Field(schema_product.Product)
    all_products = MongoengineConnectionField(schema_product.Product)

class Mutations(graphene.ObjectType):
    createProduct = schema_product.CreateProduct.Field()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, types=[schema_product.Product], mutation=Mutations)
```

Comment: Are you sure your images aren't encoded as strings using, say, base64?  It seems rather suspicious if the string you get is composed entirely of printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

It's very suspicious that:

1. Your binary data is stored in a `String` (this is usually wrong).
2. Your `String` happens to be composed entirely of printable characters.

It's therefore likely that you're getting back binary data that's been *encoded* to a printable string.  A common encoding is base64, and sure enough, when I tried to base64-encode a few different types of images, I see that base64-encoding JPEG files generates a string that starts off with `/9j/4AAQSk`, just like the string you get.

You are definitely getting back base64-encoded data.  If you aren't doing the encoding yourself, then something is automatically doing the encoding for you, and likely there's a symmetric mechanism to decode it for you.  If not, you'll need to explicitly base64-decode your `String` to get back binary data. You can use [dart:convert](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-convert/base64-constant.html) to decode it for you.

Comment: Hey thanks, I should have realised that it was in fact base64! So basically the bytes were coming from pythons `open(file, 'rb')` which gives the `b'<STRING>'` bytes representation which is then fine with mongodb, but when graphene hands the data back its a string like `"b'<STRING>'"` so the bytes representations becomes a string. I simply "sliced" the string `String byteString = allProductsItem['thumb']['data'];  Uint8List thumbImage = base64.decode(byteString.substring(2, byteString.length - 1));`