# How Can i convert text plain to base64

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting image text plain output from APi like this:

```
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...
```

How can I covert it to Uint8List?

Comment: Here is how to convert a String to Uint8List: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613234/convert-a-string-of-uint8list-to-a-unit8list

Comment: If you have a `String` that stores base64-encoded data, just use [`base64.decode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/base64-constant.html).