# How can I compress images from API without saving it in file system in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to compress without saving in files images from API to resize image?

I found one of packages which is doing this job - `flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6` but all of these packages works onle if I am going to pick uup images from file storage and after  that to reduce size to dowload it to my app.

So can I reduce image weight? Now it is 2MB images which comes from API.

I was trying this thing:

```
 if (hubConnection.state == HubConnectionState.Connected) {
      await hubConnection.invoke('GetImage', args: [carId]).then((value) {
        carImage = value as String;
      });
      var compressed = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(carImage ?? '',
          quality: 50, percentage: 30);
      print(compressed);
      print('is it compressed?');
    }
```

But it gives me an error: `'[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(file does not exist, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAIAAABnsVYUAAAgAElEQVR4AXzBi65tWZqd1e/rY659TkRmpatsGXFHyI+BQOJJAPHkIHGxJVOUMzMizl5z/J2xduQ+kVUUtOaP/+N/90V3+x+4mA0XRxdHw1F'`

I understood it says about my `carImage` variable is not File type, but Base64 type, so if there is any chance to make image size smaller without reaching out backend devs?

Comment: Did you try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress package?
You need just convert `String` to `Uint8List` then call `FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(uint8list_var, quality)`
Here you can see convert string to uint8list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613234/convert-a-string-of-uint8list-to-a-unit8list

Comment: I ended up using flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.3, thanks to @RezaM for advise. Also I was trying to check my theory about making workload faster if I will be using images compressor in my app. So it compress greatly, but load from server isn't getting any faster t and still the same (I am getting about 50 photos from API and it has 2MB size which is pretty big)