# Flutter - How to put List<Uint8List> into shared preferences?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, uint8list

I have a list of *Unit8List* which stores data of multiple images. I want to share the list with other activities so that other activities can use the list to display the images. So how can i share using **SharedPreferences**? or is there any way that i can use to pass the list having Unit8List objects?

Comment: Have you tried my solution yet?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Yes, Your Solution  worked for me, i used `String s = String.fromCharCodes(inputAsUint8List);` for encoding. i had image data in my unit8list and it got successfully decoded and displayed the image. Thanks :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the other answer as proposed by Christopher will give incorrect results for some binary values, at least on Android. The correct approach is to use a standard binary to printable string encoding. A common one is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

```
// convert to Base64
var printableString = base64.encode(bytesIn);

// and back
var bytesOut = base64.decode(printableString);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code to essentially "convert" your `Uint8List` to a `String`, which can then be easily stored in `SharedPreferences` with the [`setString`](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences-class.html) method of the `SharePreferences` class:

```dart
String s = String.fromCharCodes(inputAsUint8List);
```

and converting back

```dart
var outputAsUint8List = Uint8List.fromList(s.codeUnits);
```

Credit to [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28565602/13250142) for the String conversion.

Alternatively(as Richard Heap suggested), you could base64 encode your data with

```dart
String s = base64.encode(inputAsList);
```

in the `dart:convert` library for potentially greater safety, though this will increase the amount of space you will use to store the string.

Comment: What if your byte array contains invalid char codes? It would be safer to base 64 encode the bytes to a string. `var s = base64.encode(inputAsList);`

Comment: @RichardHeap I don't believe this is possible. I ran a test to ensure that every possible byte is a valid char code that confirms it shouldn't be an issue. I added this as a possibility to my answer regardless with a notice that using base64 encoding will increase the amount of data that needs to be stored.

Comment: Please try storing the following byte array `<int>[13]` in Android shared preferences (using both methods) and let me know if you get the same byte array back after stopping and starting the app.

Comment: @RichardHeap Do you already know the result of that? Or do you really want me to do that? The test I did was only testing to see if the `fromCharCode` constructor worked for every possible byte and if the original data could be retrieved. Does Android's shared preferences have a restriction on what it can store or use a specific type of encoding? and is this specific to Android or does it extend to the iOS equivalent as well?

Comment: I'm suggesting you try it. I believe you will get an incorrect result, as Android will change the string value as it goes in and out of shared preferences. If that happens, it will confirm the fragility of this unusual approach vs the more normal base 64 (or hex or other ways to represent binary as a string).