# Uploading pdf generated in flutter web to S3

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-s3, flutter-web, dart-io

I am using the `pdf 3.6.0` library from pub.dev to generate a pdf in flutter web. When I save the document using `doc.save()`, I get a `Future<Uint8List>`. I want to upload this file to S3

For android/ios, I first save the `Uint8List` as a file in a temp directory, using `path_provider` and then use `file.openRead()` to get data to upload to S3 and it works perfectly.

I am unable to replicate the same process in flutter web since `dart:io` is unavailable for flutter web. Even `universal_io` does not help.

I did try to directly push the `uint8list` to s3 using the below code

```
await dio.put(
      s3PresignedURLForPUT,
      data: uint8listData,
      options: Options(
        contentType: "application/pdf",
        headers: {
          "Content-Length": length,
        },
      ),
      onSendProgress: (int sentBytes, int totalBytes) {
        double progressPercent = sentBytes / totalBytes * 100;
        print("$progressPercent %");
      },
    );
```

But when I open this file again in S3 I get an error saying: "Failed to load PDF document."

How can achieve the same result for the pdf generated for flutter web?

Comment: Please has anyone solved this problem

Comment: Long shot: Try converting to string , and then decode it on the backend. Here's a link to encode in flutter [#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565242/convert-uint8list-to-string-with-dart/28570009)

Answer (score 0):

*(would add this as comment but don't have enough reputation)*

Have you tried wrapping your uint8listData in a Stream.fromIterable(), i.e.

```
data: Stream.fromIterable(uint8listData),
```

I happened to notice dio doing this in its test files with a uint8List.